# Как получить XML строку из Document?

Tags: java, xml, dom

Как получить XML-строку, если она сгенерирована в Document? Требуется именно String, а не вывод в файл.

Answer (score 0):

Есть много способов. Из самых стандартных - через `Transformer`. Примерно так:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new StringWriter());
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);
return result.getWriter().toString();
```